# Can VS 2012 reformat/outline already completed code?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a class that has largely been re-written with find and replace. The Code is fine but the outlining is garbage.

Can VS apply the auto outlining standards to code that has already been completed? How might I trigger this?

I am somewhat familiar with editing the outlining standards in options, but haven't seen an option to reformat a section of code on command rather than completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two commands for this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to reformat entire document
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to reformat only selected lines.

You can find them in one of submenus of **Edit** menu.

What you get depends on the language. For example, in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) re-formatting works slightly differently than in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net).

Answer (score 1):

Hotkey settings via Tools » Options » Environment » Keyboard: selection command is called Edit.FormatSelection or Edit.FormatDocument.

Also Available under Edit » Advanced

What you get is determined by settings via Tools » Options » 'Language' » Formatting and is not available for every language.

Errors in code, particularly missing braces etc, will prevent reformatting.